# Image Magick or Imagick Instagram Effects

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, instagram

I would like to apply filters akin to the ones instagram does (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram#Effects) in PHP.

I can manage putting together the calls to `exec` to issue an Image Magick command, paths, reading in/out, etc., but I'm wondering if the effects that instagram offers have been open-sourced anywhere, for running again Image Magick.

I've search pretty extensively, and the closest I can come up with is this:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-instagram-filters-with-php/

I've tested these under IM 6.6.x and 6.8x and both present their own-unique bugs.
Wondering if there is a resource that anyone has for applying these filters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Fred's nice filters: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/kaleidoscopic/index.php